# Optional-Chaining does not work in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, react-scripts

In a `create-react-app` project, I am using `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` in my `.babelrc

However, I have this error: `Module parse failed: Unexpected token (22:16) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

This is all my babel dependencies:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/plugin-external-helpers": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.9.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.7",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-array-includes": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^1.1.1"
  }
}
```

- node v14.0.0
- npm 6.14.4
- react-scripts 2.1.8

What else do I need in order to get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to make sure you have installed `react-scripts` [**3.3.0+** version](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#330-2019-12-04) as it already comes with optional chaining built-in:

```
const obj = { a: `Hello` };

// Hello World
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {obj?.a}
      {obj?.b ?? ` World`}
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit nice-paper-74xbv]

Comment: I am using v2.1.8, is it safe to just upgrade react-script version?

Comment: For this, you need to read the [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#boom-breaking-change-3) and the breaking changes of 3.+. It depends on your app, but [in the usual case it is ok to upgrade](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases).

Comment: I noticed that if i upgrade react-scripts to 4+ optional chaining didnt work in my app, if i brought it down to 3.x.x then it did work! very odd... but at least i got it working now, i was running on version 2.x!