# Module parse failed: Unexpected token error in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have below code in my `StatusEditAdmission.jsx` file.

https://controlc.com/f800d4e7

I am getting `Module parse failed: Unexpected token (100:29) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.` error.

[image]

Node Version: `16.5.0`

Following is the `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "...",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.49.9",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^12.0.4",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "react-select": "^5.2.2",
    "react-toastify": "^8.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.14",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.55.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it is throwing error because optional chaining is not supported in your build configuration. What bundler are you using? What does its configuration look like?

Comment: Thanks @vighnesh153. Where should I get configuration ? How can I fix the error ?

Comment: Thanks @vighnesh153. This is my project folder structure. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsfoS.png. I didn't find "babel.config". "webpack.config" or "rollup.config". Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @vighnesh153. Here is "package.json" https://pastebin.com/N46FpJCW. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @vighnesh153. My node version is `v16.5.0`. Thanks.

Comment: Since your project is based on `create-react-app`, all the loaders must already be pre-configured for you. Also, node version doesn't seem to be an issue. This is strange. Did you try deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and re-installing the dependencies? To install the dependencies, run `npm install`.

Comment: Thanks @vighnesh153. I tired your solution but I am getting similar error now.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQXLu.png

Comment: This is really strange. Was the optional chaining working before today? Do you know what change caused this to fail? Did you add any new lib dependency or any configuration change?

Comment: Can you try the solution mentioned here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61440200/optional-chaining-does-not-work-in-create-react-app

Comment: Thanks @vighnesh153. Actually I got this project today and try to install it in my local machine. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. Please update here if the above solution works.

Comment: Thanks @vighnesh153. I tried several solutions along with yours one but none of them working. Thanks.

Comment: What `react-scripts` version did you try with?

Comment: Thanks @vighnesh153. I used `"react-scripts": "^2.1.8",`. Thanks.

Comment: As mentioned in the stackoverflow question above, can you upgrade your react-scripts version to 3+? `npm install react-scripts@3`

Comment: Thanks a Lot @vighnesh153. Finally `npm install react-scripts@3` is worked for me. Thanks a Lot.